# ADFS 4.0: Received invalid Client credentials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, adfs

Any ideas why this can happen?
Our IT had ADFS updated from version 3 to version 4. 
After the update our ASP.NET Core application gets following error:

Error Code:

```
"Unhandled remote failure. (OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: BadRequest;
Body: {\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"MSIS9623: Received invalid Client credentials. The OAuth client is not configured to authenticate using passed in client credentials.\"};)"
```

The request:

```
 https://.../adfs/oauth2/authorize?client_id=d...4c&scope=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44377%2F&state=CfDJ8...Og&resource=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44377&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44377
```

I tried also tried:

- "grant_type"="authorization_code"

Someone an idea what the "client credentials" means in this context?

Comment: is this `ADFS` or `OAuth` ?

Comment: AD FS with oauth2. AD FS provides an OAUTH and OpenIDConnect endpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADFS 4.0 throws an error if "client_secret" was sent. ADFS 3.0 has ignored that value.

The  UseOAuthAuthentication sends always an "client_secret". My **dirty** solution is to intercept the http request and remove the "client_secret". If someone has a better solution...

```
 if (securityService.IsOAuthEnabled)
 {

     HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandlerInterceptor(){};
     var options = securityService.GetOAuthOptions();
     options.BackchannelHttpHandler = clientHandler;
     app.UseOAuthAuthentication(options);
 }
```

HttpClientHandlerInterceptor:

```
 public class HttpClientHandlerInterceptor : HttpClientHandler
 {
     protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         if (request.Content is FormUrlEncodedContent)
         {
             var x = ((FormUrlEncodedContent) request.Content).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             var contenttype = request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
             x = x.Replace("client_secret=will+be+ignored&", "");
             request.Content = new StringContent(x, Encoding.UTF8, contenttype);
         }
         return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the application on the ADFS side via the wizard, you get a clientId.

This is the clientId that you pass in the request.

Check that you are passing the correct clientId.

Also look in the ADFS error log.

Comment: Found a solution. Error was: MSIS9265: Received invalid Client credentials. Found 'client_secret' query parameter in the request but the Client '620f7...c21' is not configured to authenticate using client secret post.

Answer (score 0):

Notice in your request string this:  response_type=***code***

When I commented out the UseOAuthe2CodeRedeemer from the *ConfigureAuth* function that was in *Startup.Auth.cs*, it alleviated the problem at hand.

See below:

```
        //    code_grant is present in the querystring (&code=<code>).
        //app.UseOAuth2CodeRedeemer(
        //    new OAuth2CodeRedeemerOptions
        //    {
        //        ClientId = AuthenticationConfig.ClientId,
        //        ClientSecret = AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret,
        //        RedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri
        //    }
        //);
```